# Need to execute helper methods only once (cache results)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a helper class for my MVC application. This class will contain static methods that will pull information the first time the user logs into the system.

I have created two methods that will return lists like list of countries and list of languages. I don't want to execute this every time but save results of first call and return it for subsequent calls.

```
public static List<Languages> GetLanguages()
{
   using (var db = new MCREntities())
    {
        var languages = db.spGetLanguages(0);
        return Mapper.Map<List<Languages>>(languages);

    }
}
public static List<Countries> GetCountries()
{
    using (var db = new MCREntities())
    {
        var countries = db.spGetAllCountries("");
        return Mapper.Map<List<Countries>>(countries);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your class you can have static list which would hold `Languages` anly first time would try to access database.

```
private static List<Languages> _languages = null;

public static List<Languages> GetLanguages()
{
    if(_languages == null){
        using (var db = new MCREntities())
        {
            var languages = db.spGetLanguages(0);
            _languages = Mapper.Map<List<Languages>>(languages);

        }
    }
    return _languages;
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement [cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Interesting. I plan to pull userprofile information in similar manner. What if I have updated the userprofile information. How do I update this list.

Comment: It's `static` class, so it wont work as you want with user profile

Comment: Consider the userprofile has been updated in the database. I would then want to update my list with the laytest userprofile

Comment: Code in the post is generally bad recommendation for multi-threaded environment like ASP.Net, but just due to luck code works correctly (but obviously does not  guarantee that call will be made once). So had to avoid downvoting as it *happen* to not be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i would say create a class with the required properties liek

```
public static class  CurrentSession{ 
 List<Languages> lang{get;set;}
List<Countries> countries{get;set;} 
}
```

and in global.asax file

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
//.........predefined codes

    CurrentSession.lang = GetLanguages();

    CurrentSession.Countries =GetCountries();
```

Comment: So the static methods are in the helper itself right ? I just need to create this additional static class and write logic in the application_start

Comment: yep the advantage is that your Current session will initialize at the start and you can call anywhere in the app just add the required calls